# How to hide and show (in forelse loop) div (in array) based on a selection of radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

I have question regarding to for loop. I have radio button which will store value of Hadir (Attending) and Tidak (Not Attending). If we selected Tidak, div will be show. Otherwise, it will hide the div. My problem is my radio button and div is in for loop. Div will show according to current index and selected radio button. Div show and hide is working, but if we got for next user, the process of show or hide is not working. Below is input for radio button.

```
@forelse($ahli_mesyuarat as $counter => $ahli)

<?php $counter++; ?>
<form class="theme-form mega-form" name="formkehadiran" method="POST">
{{csrf_field()}}
<tr>
<td>{{ $counter }}</td>
<td align="center"><strong>({{$ahli->nama_ahli}})</strong><br>{{$ahli->Jawatan->nama_jawatan}}</td>
<td align="center">{{$ahli->Gred->nama_gred}} <br> {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($ahli->tarikh_lantikan)) }}</td>


<td><strong>
 <div class="form-group" align="center">
  <label  class="col-form-label" for="hadir">HADIR</label>
  <input style="width:9%;" type="radio" id="radioYes" name="kehadiran[{{$counter}}]" value="Y" onClick="hideInputDiv();" checked>
                                                
 <label class="col-form-label" for="tidakHadir">TIDAK HADIR</label>
 <input style="width:9%;" type="radio" id="radioNo" name="kehadiran[{{$counter}}]" value="N" onchange="addmentor()">
 </div> 


<!-- My Div that need to be hide and show -->
 
 <div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">
  CATATAN(JIKA TIDAK HADIR):
  <textarea class="form-control" name="catatan[{{$counter}}]" id="" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder=""></textarea><br>
 
  NAMA WAKIL
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="wakil_oleh[{{$counter}}]" placeholder="NAMA PENUH WAKIL" value=""><br>
 
  JAWATAN WAKIL
  <select class="form-control" name="jawatan" id="jawatan" value="jawatan">
  <option label="PILIH JAWATAN WAKIL"></option>
  <optgroup label ="____________________________________________________________________">
   @foreach ($ref_jawatan as $ahli_mesyuarats)
    <option value="{{ $ahli_mesyuarats->id_jawatan }}">{{ $ahli_mesyuarats->nama_jawatan }} </option>
   @endforeach
  </select><br>
 
  GRED WAKIL
  <select class="form-control" name="id_gred" id="id_gred" value="id_gred">
  <optgroup label="PILIH GRED AHLI">
  <option label="PILIH GRED AHLI MESYUARAT"></option>
  <optgroup label ="____________________________________________________________________">
   @foreach ($kekananan_gred as $ahli_mesyuarats)
    <option value="{{ $ahli_mesyuarats->id_gred }}">{{ $ahli_mesyuarats->nama_gred }}</option>
   @endforeach
  </select>
 </div>
</strong></td>
```

Lastly is script. It is outside the foreach loop.

```
<script>
    //your checkbox
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("radioNo");

    //your div
    var inputDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");

    //function that will show hidden inputs when clicked
    function addmentor() {
    if (checkbox.checked = true) {
        inputDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
    }

    //function that will hide the inputs when another checkbox is clicked
    function hideInputDiv() {
    inputDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

I hope someone can help with this. Tq in adv.

Comment: The first <select> missing </select>

Comment: `document.getElementById("radioNo[{{$counter}}]");` What is `$counter`? If your script is in a loop, that will generate multiple instances of `var checkbox`, which would be one of several problems. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73955790/edit) to show a short example of the generated code (not the source) so we can understand the exact DOM layout.

Comment: @TheKNVB I have edit for more convinent to see.

Comment: @kmoser The script is outside the loop sir. document.getElementById("radioNo[{{$counter}}]"); is me trying to run it if the radioNo will show the div or not base on array [{{$counter}}] value. Nothing is happening here.

Comment: @kmoser I have edit sir.

Comment: What is the value of `$counter` in `document.getElementById("radioNo[{{$counter}}]");`? If it simply contains the last value in the loop, then it will only point to the last radio button generated.

Comment: @kmoser Okay, now I understand your concern. Then how I want to make sure that every index in loop working just fine to show and hide the div?I have delete [{{$counter}}] in radioNo[{{$counter}}] input and document.getElementById. But when I go for next person (2nd person), the process of showing the div is not working. How can you help with that sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alhamdulillah. I have found a way to solve it. Below is the change in onclick

```
<label  class="col-form-label" for="radioYes{{$counter}}">HADIR</label>
<input style="width:9%;" type="radio" id="radioYes{{$counter}}" name="kehadiran[{{$counter}}]" value="Y" onclick="hideInputDiv({{$counter}})" checked>
                                                                                                
<label class="col-form-label" for="radioNo{{$counter}}">TIDAK HADIR</label>
<input style="width:9%;" type="radio" id="radioNo{{$counter}}" name="kehadiran[{{$counter}}]" value="N" onclick="addmentor({{$counter}})">
```

Next is script which need to be in the loop.

```
<script>
 function addmentor(index) {
                                                   
  document.getElementById('myDIV' + index).style.display = "block";
 }

 function hideInputDiv(index) {
  document.getElementById('myDIV' + index).style.display = "none";
 }
</script>
```

Here how I put counter in div.

```
 <div id="myDIV{{$counter}}" style="display: none;">
    CATATAN(JIKA TIDAK HADIR):
    <textarea class="form-control" name="catatan[{{$counter}}]" id="" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder=""></textarea><br>
    NAMA WAKIL
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="wakil_oleh[{{$counter}}]" placeholder="NAMA PENUH WAKIL" value=""><br>
    JAWATAN WAKIL
    <select class="form-control" name="jawatan_wakil[{{$counter}}]" id="jawatan_wakil" value="jawatan_wakil">
    <option label="PILIH JAWATAN WAKIL"></option>
    <optgroup label ="____________________________________________________________________">
       @foreach ($ref_jawatan as $ahli_mesyuarats)
       <option value="{{ $ahli_mesyuarats->id_jawatan }}">{{ $ahli_mesyuarats->nama_jawatan }} </option>
       @endforeach
    </select><br>
    GRED WAKIL
    <select class="form-control" name="id_gred_wakil[{{$counter}}]" id="id_gred_wakil" value="id_gred_wakil">
    <optgroup label="PILIH GRED AHLI">
    <option label="PILIH GRED AHLI MESYUARAT"></option>
    <optgroup label ="____________________________________________________________________">
       @foreach ($kekananan_gred as $ahli_mesyuarats)
       <option value="{{ $ahli_mesyuarats->id_gred }}">{{ $ahli_mesyuarats->nama_gred }}</option>
       @endforeach
    </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons need to have unique IDs, and the labels need to reference those IDs.

```
<label  class="col-form-label" for="radioYes{{$counter}}">HADIR</label>
<input style="width:9%;" type="radio" id="radioYes{{$counter}}" name="kehadiran[{{$counter}}]" value="Y" onClick="hideInputDiv();" checked>
                                                
<label class="col-form-label" for="radioNo{{$counter}}">TIDAK HADIR</label>
<input style="width:9%;" type="radio" id="radioNo{{$counter}}" name="kehadiran[{{$counter}}]" value="N" onclick="addmentor()">
```

Then change your Javascript to this:

```
function addmentor() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
}
```

There is no need to examine the value of the checkbox, since the function only gets called when the user clicks one of the "tidak hadir" radio buttons.

This could probably be improved further to account for users using the keyboard to change the radio values (rather than clicking).

Comment: Sorry sir. But it is not working.

Comment: @AineelZihnee "Not working" does not give me enough details to help you. You will have to be more specific. Are there errors in the console?

Comment: The console inform that cannot read properties of null.

Comment: @ksomer I am sorry, I have look up. I added counter in my div. But after I remove the counter and follow your way, same thing happen. Only first person will show the div.

Comment: @AineelZihnee See my updated Javascript. Change `inputDiv` to `document.getElementById("myDIV")`.

Comment: Sir, I have see and follow your step. Still same sir. Only first person only show the div.

Comment: @AineelZihnee You would need to edit your question to show the generated HTML, not your PHP code. Without seeing your generated HTML (and JS), it's impossible to tell what is going on.

Comment: It is okay Sir. My question is straight foward. I am waiting other to share what is their thought. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for giving idea for assign unique IDs.